# POST to PHP script executes but gives error 520

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a form that a user fills out, that has their first name, last name, email, and year of graduation. I use jQuery send it to a PHP form called `form.php`, which does something, and then returns the string `success` to the frontend. This was working previously, but I just added a couple more lines, and now it gives a 520 when I send a POST request to it:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 520 (HTTP/2.0 520)
```

However, *everything* in the script executes as it should, and there are no (known) syntax errors. The file is on github and can be found here: https://github.com/LAHSHackClub/lahs.club/blob/master/form.php

When looking through my PHP logs, it successfully calls the request to `form.php`:

```
[Mon Aug 28 05:31:21 2017] 127.0.0.1:33480 [200]: /form.php
```

(it's in green on the command line, meaning it executed)

This isn't really game-breaking other than the fact that it doesn't send a success message. I could make a workaround but I feel like I should get this resolved. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try using another name other than form.php. maybe it will help

Comment: `This was working previously, but I just added a couple more lines...` - what you added? Do you tryed to take a look into  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520-Web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error  and https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/222971907-Using-cURL-when-Troubleshooting-with-Cloudflare pages?

Comment: @user3808887 But it was working before... that would have nothing to do with it. @Neodan It was more `exec()`s, I don't think it'd change anything. And yes, I saw that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of JesseTheSkrub, I fixed it! Essentially, the last `exec` was:

```
exec('service apache2 reload');
```

Which basically cut off the connection to the server in the middle of the file, and hence giving a 520. In order to solve this, PHP has a handy function: `ignore_user_abort(true);`, which I plopped on line 1 to fix. Thanks Jesse!

Answer (score 0):

The 520 error is essentially a “catch-all” response for when the origin server returns something unexpected or something that is not tolerated/interpreted (protocol violation or empty response).

For your case, it would most probably be a server timeout or server form.php response null OR  no response u get.

*Empty response from origin*

Comment: 1. Server timeout: can a php script time out even if it fully executes? 2. Response null: I've looked at all cases, it couldn't be null. Check my github repo. 3. Empty response: again, impossible. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

````
problem with the request/url, you may not get json back.
I get it now..
Problem in your form.js you set JSON request in $.post

 ``` $_POST['first_name'] is for the form-xxx data  ```
 Thats u get NULL response
````

You need to create form and try ths syntext in AJEX

```
var data =$('#formid').serialize();

send 'data' to form.php in AJEX
```

Comment: $_POST['first_name'] this not get json data u pass json so not get value okky if u not believe use POSTMAN for check request

Comment: `$_POST['first_name']` is not the issue because it was working before, and I am passing an input value, which is a STRING. This should not give an error 520 either.

Comment: hey IF u don't find
just try POSTMAN to check request